# Subtraction/addition as an argumnet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I make the following class method receive an argument that controls whether the position (at the end) should be subtracted or added `1`? The value is always `1`.

```
def self.update_position(arg)
  self.where(active: true).update_all('position = (position - 1)')
end
```

Comment: How would I use it in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could interpolate into your string:

```
def self.update_position(arg)
  self.where(active: true).update_all("position = (position #{arg} 1)")
end
```

Which presumes you're going to call `Class.update_position('-')` or `Class.update_position('+')`.

Personally, I'd take it one step further and prevent the risk of injection by passing an argument that isn't directly interpolated into the string:

```
def self.update_position(arg)
  operator = (arg.to_s == 'up' ? '+' : '-')
  self.where(active: true).update_all("position = (position #{operator} 1)")
end
```

So this way you can call `Class.update_position(:up)` to increment, or anything else to decrement (`Class.update_position(:down)`).